# Replicate Database

Tags: replication

I want to execute proc of database 'A' from database 'B'. My situation is this that I have a database 'A' and a database 'B'. I want that when a proc is executed on database 'A' it will also execute on database 'B'. This is because the whole structure is the same on both databases but some procs are different in database 'B'. I want to match the result effected by both procs in DB 'A' and DB 'B'. Is there is any solution for this problem? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might help if you state the DBMS you're using!

Comment: It will depend on your database: SQL Server , Oracle ...?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server transactional replication, it is possible: [Publishing Stored Procedure Execution in Transactional Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152754(SQL.90).aspx) and [Replicate Stored Procedure Execution](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Replication/61332/)

Comment: I am using sql server 2005.I hv done transactional replication and all procs are replicated but when i do changes in publisher ('A') DB it only reflects the changes of table in DB 'B',bt i want that the changes should hit DB 'B' using 'B' proc.How to publish stored proc execution in sql server 2005.

Comment: I need both DB execute their own procs when updation is done in DB 'A'.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what DBMS are you using?

MySQL replicates stored procedures when using DB replication, so basic MySQL replication should just work.

Comment: I am using sql server 2005.Is it possible replication of stored procedures in sql server 2005?I have done replication and all procs are replicated but when i do changes in publisher ('A') DB it only reflects the changes of table in DB 'B', bt i want that the changes should hit DB 'B' using 'B' proc.

Comment: I need both DB execute their own procs when updation is done in DB 'A'.

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure, I never used MSSQL.